# Rotate a gameobject in a specific angle left or right

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

So basically what I am trying to do is when I move my character via joystick I want to calculate the current angle the character is rotating and the new angle in which he should rotate. for example: i am moving the joystick to 45 degrees so my character is rotating at 45 degrees to right. now I move the joystick to 90 degrees. So basically I want to calculate the difference between the current and new angle and than rotate at that specific angle. In this case it would be 45 degrees to left and my character should rotate 45 degrees to left.

Whats the best way to do it?

```
 void Update()
 {
     // move
     _rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * leftController.GetTouchPosition.y * Time.deltaTime * speedMovements) +
         (transform.right * leftController.GetTouchPosition.x * Time.deltaTime * speedMovements) );

     if (myX != leftController.GetTouchPosition.x || myY != leftController.GetTouchPosition.y) { //checks if player changed position.
         myX = leftController.GetTouchPosition.x;
         myY = leftController.GetTouchPosition.y;

         double rad = Mathf.Atan2(leftController.GetTouchPosition.y, leftController.GetTouchPosition.x); // In radians
         double deg = rad * (180 / System.Math.PI); // values from up right to up left : +0 to +180 and from down left to down right: -180 to -0

     //    double difference =....; here i want to calc the angle my char. should rotate 
     //    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,(float)difference * Time.deltaTime);

     }
```

Comment: I think a general formula would be `diff = sensitivity * speed * deltaTime * deltaJoy`